# awk what is wrong with my syntax?

Tags: awk

```
awk 'if(NF==7){print$1":"$2":"$4":"$5, $7, $6}else {print$1":"$2":"$3":"$4, $6, $5}'
awk: if(NF==7){print$1":"$2":"$4":"$5, $7, $6}else {print$1":"$2":"$3":"$4, $6, $5}
awk: ^ syntax error
```

What is the syntax error here? the arrow points to the if

Comment: Enclose whole if in `{ }`

Comment: alternatively `awk 'NF==7 {print$1":"$2":"$4":"$5, $7, $6;next} {print$1":"$2":"$3":"$4, $6, $5}'`

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is a series of `condition {action}` statements.

`if` is not valid condition. You need to enclose that in an action block:

```
awk '{if(something) { do something } else { do something else }}'
```

Alternatively, you can leave off the `if` for the conditions of `NF==7` for example:

```
awk 'NF==7{ do something; next } { do something else }'
```

The second is more idiomatic `awk` for testing `NF`, other built-in variables or other variables in general.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code as:

```
awk '{print $1":"$2":" (NF==7 ? $4":"$5, $7, $6 : $3":"$4, $6, $5)}'
```

and start reading Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.